# how to capture a video from /dev port in linux using java

Tags: java, linux

i am trying to capture video from my /dev/video1 usb camera using java, i was wondering as to how to actually do this? my project is supposed to capture the video and stream it to another computer. is it also possible to set up an avconv server using java?

Comment: Related to your first question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504191/capture-live-video-from-webcam-using-java

Answer (score 1):

It's already been done for you so you might take a look into the existing projects.

[**v4l4j** wouble be a great place to start](http://code.google.com/p/v4l4j/).

**update**
As [Andy Ross](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9555/andy-ross) commented the library I linked is very low level and you may be looking into something more easy to use as **[gstreamer-java](http://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java)**.

Comment: Probably better to look at "gstreamer-java" (http://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/ which I've never tried nor heard of before just now).  V4L2 is the low level API which gives you a bunch of raw frames.  Generally when someone wants to "capture the video and stream it to another computer" they expect encoded video with synchronized audio.  The proper API for that is gstreamer.

Comment: @Andy Ross thks for the input. Gonna update the answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have an extensive support for media. You can use [GStreamer](http://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/) JNI bindings for this or switch to [QT](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/phonon-videoplayer.html) or native C/C++ [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/).